# Get users in WordPress with an array of exceptions

Tags: wordpress

If I wanted to get a list of users in WordPress with an exception of users, how would I do this?  So to get a complete list of users I could write a query like:

```
$dont_include = array(1,5,9);  // IDs not to include

$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE ID > 0 AND ID != %d";
$data = array(
     $dont_include
);
$query = $wpdb->prepare($query, $data);
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

Comment: Don't write SQL queries if you can do it via one of the core APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily with the WordPress function `get_users` and the `exclude` parameter:

```
$dont_include = array(1,5,9);  // IDs not to include
$args = array(
    'exclude'      => $dont_include,
    'orderby'      => 'login',
    'order'        => 'ASC',
    'fields'       => 'all',
);
$users = get_users($args);
```

exclude - An array of IDs. Users matching these IDs will not be returned, regardless of the other arguments. It will be ignored if the include argument is set.

More details [get_users](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)

Comment: This was it.  Sorry for the years in-between ;) . I found the codex shortly after writing this question back in 2016 and never came back.  Kuddos @Benoti